# Why if I use the 'var' variable and then delete it in the code, does it stay in memory and I can use it again? Is it normal behavior for JAVA SCRIPT?

Tags: javascript

### (sorry for my English)

I had not found such stragnes in other langs, is this normal?

```
//first step
//browser console show 100
var num = 100;
console.log(num);

//second - clean js file and try use variable again
//browser show 100 again, but variable have not defined, I am afraid such pranks...
console.log(num);
```

Comment: If you remove `var num = 100;` from your JavaScript and refresh the page (and nothing else causes `num` to have a value), then it shouldn't show `100`. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: What do you mean by "clean js file"? Did you also reload the browser page?

Comment: No, I mean that I remove code in js file and write only console.log(name)

Answer (score -1):

Your first JS file defines "num" as a global variable. All JS files have access to this global scope. Therefore, when you log the variable in code in another JS file, that global variable remains.

Answer (score -1):

First when you use Javascript don't manage money because it's a scriptable language . and you have to define you varables in function or class or add to object becose anything outsie is a global access